# Check Hexadecimal Representation of a QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qbytearray

How does one check for specific values in a QByteArray?

Something like this:

```
QByteArray example;
//...
example = file.readAll();//fill with data from a file
//...
if(example.mid(0, 2) == 0x0a00)
    //do something
```

The above doesn't work.

I CAN do this but I am currently fixing performance issues so I'd rather **not** have to convert it to a QString:

```
QByteArray example;
//...
example = file.readAll();//fill with data from a file
//...
if(example.mid(0, 2).toHex() == "0a00")
    //do something
```

What's the fastest way to check the bytes in a QByteArray based on their hex representation?

Comment: Sadly asking, "What's a QByte?" has gone out of fashion. Curse you Bill Cosby!

Answer (score -1):

You can compare simply like this.

if(example.mid(0, 2) == "\x0a\x00")

Edited:
This is not working. Check below comment.

Comment: I just tried that, and when I KNOW example.mid(0,2) is 0a00, when trying what you said, it acted as if they were different.

Comment: Sorry, that need QString. How about use [] operator than mid method? [] operator overrided for char to return.

Comment: How would I check multiple bytes at a time like that then? Would that be slower than .mid? Also, since it's read only, wouldn't .at() be better than []?

Comment: I think the above is getting tripped up because of the \x00 (ie NUL terminator) in the string. How about
  `if (example.mid(0, 2) == QByteArray::fromRawData("\x0a\x00", 2))`

Comment: As for using [], you want `if (example[0] == 0x0a && example[1] == 0x00)` obviously...

Comment: Thanks Hamish. Unfortunately, simply adding another condition in the if statement wouldn't work for my whole project since at times I check larger amounts of data than just two bytes. Also, fromRawData did work. :) Do you know if toHex is faster or slower than fromRawData?